# background и прозрачность

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

У меня есть svg-файл для задника.

Вот как он выглядит (соответственно, могу менять заливку этих бубликов внутри svg-кода)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, имеется следующий дизайн-проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что выше и ниже, я обрезал.
Застрял именно на данном этапе.

Применил для верхней трети (What we offer) полупрозрачный фон - сработало;
а дальше никак не могу выйти на нужные цвета фона и бубликов.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно умело жонглировать RGB и RGBA, может быть есть удобные конвертеры etc..

Comment: Не понял в чем проблема?Не получается сделать двухцветный круг?

Comment: не совсем так, круги уже есть в svg-файле. нужно сделать так, чтобы при попаданий на один из трёх сегментов, эти круги меняли свою заливку. фиксированный вариант можно сделать, но речь о резиновой вёрстке. поэтому вопрос либо фильтров, либо ещё чего-то

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle r="70" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="#5498C5" stroke-width="55"></circle>
  <circle r="70" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="55" stroke-dasharray="220" stroke-dashoffset="110"></circle>
</svg>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle r="70" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="#5498C5" stroke-width="55"></circle>
  <circle r="70" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="55" stroke-dasharray="220" ></circle>
</svg>

svg {
  background-color:#C5DBE9;
}
```